# CXF Circuit Breaker For JAx RS

Tags: rest, client, cxf, cxfrs

I am looking at the Circuit Breaker Implementation for CXF

**http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-failover.html**

Am not able to find this "**clustering:circuit-breaker-failover**" tag in the schema. I am not able to find a working sample as well.

has some one used this?. Why is it that I cant find this in the XSD.

http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/clustering.xsd

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the last modified date on clustering.xsd is 2012-05-24 13:01. I guess it has not been updated, yet. May be you can ignore this xsd error in the IDE and build it. It may still work.

Comment: I tried Doing that but my IDE throws error "nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [circuit-breaker-failover]".

It is funny that even the sample they have on GitHub does some one line Dummy call.

Comment: It's here: https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/ac9b9b1898bbe0cc911b34cc3d32664ac59fdc34/systests/uncategorized/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/systest/clustering/circuit_breaker_failover.xml
And the bean has gotta be here in this package:org.apache.cxf.clustering.circuitbreaker; Try to see if you can somehow put these things together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature will be available starting from CXF 3.2.0 due in a couple of months - I've updated the documentation and the schema accordingly, thanks.